# How do I use ResolveIpNetEntry2 in C#

Tags: c#, network-programming, ipv6

I am attempting to retrieve the MAC address of an IPv6 host in C#. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085304/get-a-remote-mac-adress-via-ipv6) which mentions using ResolveIpNetEntry2. After some googling, and referencing the MSDN, I haven't found an example of how to call this function from C#. This function is also unlisted on pinvoke.net.

Does anyone have an example of how to call ResolveIpNetEntry2 from C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a class showing the structures needed and how to make the call to ResolveIpNetEntry2:

```
class ResolveMac
{
    private const short AF_INET6 = 23;

    #region Structs for ResolveIpNetEntry2

    struct MIB_IPNET_ROW2
    {
        public SOCKADDR_INET Address;
        public uint InterfaceIndex;
        public ulong InterfaceLuid;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32)]
        public byte[] PhysicalAddress;

        public uint PhysicalAddressLength;
        public NL_NEIGHBOR_STATE State;
        public byte Flags;
        public uint LastReachable;
    }

    private struct SOCKADDR_INET
    {
        public SOCKADDR_IN6 Ipv6;
    }

    private struct SOCKADDR_IN6
    {
        public short sin6_family;
        public ushort sin6_port;
        public uint sin6_flowinfo;
        public in6_addr sin6_addr;
        public uint sin6_scope_id;
    }

    struct in6_addr
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
        public byte[] Byte;
    }

    #endregion

    private enum NL_NEIGHBOR_STATE
    {
        NlnsUnreachable,
        NlnsIncomplete,
        NlnsProbe,
        NlnsDelay,
        NlnsStale,
        NlnsReachable,
        NlnsPermanent,
        NlnsMaximum
    }

    [DllImport("Iphlpapi.dll")]
    private static extern int ResolveIpNetEntry2(ref MIB_IPNET_ROW2 Row,
        ref SOCKADDR_INET SourceAddress);

    public static byte[] GetMacFromIPv6Address(IPAddress ipv6Address)
    {
        if (ipv6Address.AddressFamily != 
            System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "The IPAddress provided was not an IPv6 address.");

        //set up target address
        MIB_IPNET_ROW2 row2 = new MIB_IPNET_ROW2();
        row2.PhysicalAddress = new byte[32];
        row2.State = NL_NEIGHBOR_STATE.NlnsReachable;
        row2.Address.Ipv6.sin6_addr.Byte = new byte[16];
        row2.Address.Ipv6.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
        row2.Address.Ipv6.sin6_flowinfo = 0;
        row2.Address.Ipv6.sin6_port = 0;
        row2.Address.Ipv6.sin6_scope_id = Convert.ToUInt32(ipv6Address.ScopeId);

        byte[] ipv6AddressBytes = ipv6Address.GetAddressBytes();
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(ipv6AddressBytes, 0, 
            row2.Address.Ipv6.sin6_addr.Byte, 0, ipv6AddressBytes.Length);

        //get this machine's local IPv6 address
        SOCKADDR_INET sock = new SOCKADDR_INET();
        sock.Ipv6.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
        sock.Ipv6.sin6_flowinfo = 0;
        sock.Ipv6.sin6_port = 0;
        sock.Ipv6.sin6_addr.Byte = new byte[16];

        IPAddress[] addresses = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (IPAddress address in addresses)
        {
            if (address.AddressFamily == 
                System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)
            {
                sock.Ipv6.sin6_addr.Byte = address.GetAddressBytes();
                break;
            }
        }

        foreach (NetworkInterface netInterface in 
            NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            if (netInterface.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
            {
                row2.InterfaceIndex = (uint)clsNetworkStats.GetInterfaceIndex(
                    netInterface.Description);
                break;
            }
        }

        int result = ResolveIpNetEntry2(ref row2, ref sock);

        if (result != 0)
            throw new ApplicationException(
                "The call to ResolveIpNetEntry2 failed; error number: " + 
                result.ToString());

        byte[] macAddress = new byte[6];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(row2.PhysicalAddress, 0, macAddress, 0, 6);

        return macAddress;
    }

}
```

Basically, just ping the target host, and feed the address returned to this function.

The class clsNetworkStats is used to determine the InterfaceIndex that should be used. I found this code example [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/3347a33a-1562-4643-ad80-0823e19a37f0/) and modified it slightly.

```
internal class clsNetworkStats
{
    // Fields
    private const long ERROR_SUCCESS = 0L;
    private ArrayList m_Adapters;
    private const long MAX_INTERFACE_NAME_LEN = 0x100L;
    private const long MAXLEN_IFDESCR = 0x100L;
    private const long MAXLEN_PHYSADDR = 8L;

    // Methods
    public clsNetworkStats()
        : this(true)
    {
    }
    public clsNetworkStats(bool IgnoreLoopBack)
    {
        int lRetSize = 0;
        MIB_IFROW ifrow = new MIB_IFROW();
        byte[] buff = new byte[1];
        byte val = 0;
        long ret = GetIfTable(ref val, ref lRetSize, 0);
        buff = new byte[lRetSize];
        ret = GetIfTable(ref buff[0], ref lRetSize, 0);
        int lRows = buff[0];
        this.m_Adapters = new ArrayList(lRows);
        byte len = (byte)lRows;
        for (byte i = 1; i <= len; i++)
        {
            ifrow = new MIB_IFROW();
            ifrow.dwIndex = Convert.ToUInt32(i);
            ret = GetIfEntry(ref ifrow);
            IFROW_HELPER ifhelp = this.PrivToPub(ifrow);
            if (IgnoreLoopBack)
            {
                if (ifhelp.Description.IndexOf("Loopback") < 0)
                {
                    this.m_Adapters.Add(ifhelp);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.m_Adapters.Add(ifhelp);
            }
        }
    }

    public IFROW_HELPER GetAdapter(int index)
    {
        return (IFROW_HELPER)this.m_Adapters[index];
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return this.m_Adapters.Count;
        }
    }

    [DllImport("iphlpapi")]
    private static extern int GetIfEntry(ref MIB_IFROW pIfRow);
    [DllImport("iphlpapi")]
    private static extern int GetIfTable(ref byte pIfRowTable, ref int pdwSize, int bOrder);
    //[DebuggerStepThrough]
    private IFROW_HELPER PrivToPub(MIB_IFROW pri)
    {
        IFROW_HELPER ifhelp = new IFROW_HELPER();
        ifhelp.Name = pri.wszName.Trim();
        ifhelp.Index = Convert.ToInt32(pri.dwIndex);
        ifhelp.Type = Convert.ToInt32(pri.dwType);
        ifhelp.Mtu = Convert.ToInt32(pri.dwMtu);
        ifhelp.Speed = Convert.ToInt32(pri.dwSpeed);
        ifhelp.PhysAddrLen = Convert.ToInt32(pri.dwPhysAddrLen);
        ifhelp.PhysAddr = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(pri.bPhysAddr);
        ifhelp.AdminStatus = Convert.ToInt32(pri.dwAdminStatus);
        ifhelp.OperStatus = Convert.ToInt32(pri.dwOperStatus);
        ifhelp.LastChange = Convert.ToInt32(pri.dwLastChange);
        ifhelp.InOctets = pri.dwInOctets; //Convert.ToInt32(pri.dwInOctets);
        ifhelp.InUcastPkts = Convert.ToInt32(pri.dwInUcastPkts);
        ifhelp.InNUcastPkts = Convert.ToInt32(pri.dwInNUcastPkts);
        ifhelp.InDiscards = Convert.ToInt32(pri.dwInDiscards);
        ifhelp.InErrors = Convert.ToInt32(pri.dwInErrors);
        ifhelp.InUnknownProtos = Convert.ToInt32(pri.dwInUnknownProtos);
        ifhelp.OutOctets = pri.dwOutOctets;//Convert.ToInt32(pri.dwOutOctets);
        ifhelp.OutUcastPkts = Convert.ToInt32(pri.dwOutUcastPkts);
        ifhelp.OutNUcastPkts = Convert.ToInt32(pri.dwOutNUcastPkts);
        ifhelp.OutDiscards = Convert.ToInt32(pri.dwOutDiscards);
        ifhelp.OutErrors = Convert.ToInt32(pri.dwOutErrors);
        ifhelp.OutQLen = Convert.ToInt32(pri.dwOutQLen);
        ifhelp.Description = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(pri.bDescr, 0, Convert.ToInt32(pri.dwDescrLen));
        ifhelp.InMegs = this.ToMegs((long)ifhelp.InOctets);
        ifhelp.OutMegs = this.ToMegs((long)ifhelp.OutOctets);
        return ifhelp;
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    private string ToMegs(long lSize)
    {
        string sDenominator = " B";
        if (lSize > 0x3e8L)
        {
            sDenominator = " KB";
            lSize = (long)Math.Round((double)(((double)lSize) / 1000.0));
        }
        else if (lSize <= 0x3e8L)
        {
            sDenominator = " B";
            //            lSize = lSize;
        }

        return lSize.ToString("###,###") + sDenominator;
        //            (Strings.Format(lSize, "###,###0") + sDenominator);
    }

    // Nested Types
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct IFROW_HELPER
    {
        public string Name;
        public int Index;
        public int Type;
        public int Mtu;
        public int Speed;
        public int PhysAddrLen;
        public string PhysAddr;
        public int AdminStatus;
        public int OperStatus;
        public int LastChange;
        public uint InOctets;   //changed
        public int InUcastPkts;
        public int InNUcastPkts;
        public int InDiscards;
        public int InErrors;
        public int InUnknownProtos;
        public uint OutOctets;  //changed
        public int OutUcastPkts;
        public int OutNUcastPkts;
        public int OutDiscards;
        public int OutErrors;
        public int OutQLen;
        public string Description;
        public string InMegs;
        public string OutMegs;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private struct MIB_IFROW
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 0x100)]
        public string wszName;
        public uint dwIndex;
        public uint dwType;
        public uint dwMtu;
        public uint dwSpeed;
        public uint dwPhysAddrLen;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
        public byte[] bPhysAddr;
        public uint dwAdminStatus;
        public uint dwOperStatus;
        public uint dwLastChange;
        public uint dwInOctets;
        public uint dwInUcastPkts;
        public uint dwInNUcastPkts;
        public uint dwInDiscards;
        public uint dwInErrors;
        public uint dwInUnknownProtos;
        public uint dwOutOctets;
        public uint dwOutUcastPkts;
        public uint dwOutNUcastPkts;
        public uint dwOutDiscards;
        public uint dwOutErrors;
        public uint dwOutQLen;
        public uint dwDescrLen;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 0x100)]
        public byte[] bDescr;
    }

    public static int GetInterfaceIndex(string description)
    {
        int val = 0;

        clsNetworkStats stats = new clsNetworkStats();
        for (int index = 0; index < stats.Count; index++)
        {
            string desc = stats.GetAdapter(index).Description;
            if (desc == description + "\0")
            {
                val = stats.GetAdapter(index).Index;
                break;
            }
        }

        return val;
    }
}
```

Comment: An easier way to get the interface index is the function GetBestInterfaceEx() https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getbestinterfaceex